# Рендеринг html в asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html

Здравствуйте! У меня такой вопрос. Если я хочу отрендерить на view другое view то я могу использовать такой код:

```
@Html.Partial("Myiew")
```

Однако если я хочу отрендерить не представление, а некую html-страницу (именно страницу, а не какое-то другое представление) то когда пишу так:

```
@Html.Partial("MyPage.html")
```

то получаю ошибку The partial view 'MyPage.html' was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations.

При том, что страница MyPage.html точно существует, а в пути к ней нет ошибок(даже решарпер свидетельствует об этом). Как мне отрендерить эту html-страницу на моем представлении? Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Метод [`PartialExtensions.Partial(HtmlHelper, string)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee402898(v=vs.108).aspx) принимает **имя** partial view. Как вы понимаете, `"MyPage.html"` таковым не является: это просто имя файла. Получив на вход такое значение, *view engine* будет искать следующие файлы в таком порядке (для Razor view engine):

```
~/Views/[ControllerName]/MyPage.html.cshtml
~/Views/[ControllerName]/MyPage.html.vbhtml
~/Views/Shared/MyPage.html.cshtml
~/Views/Shared/MyPage.html.vbhtml
```

Вижу два способа сделать то, что вам нужно:

**1)** Создать вспомогательный метод, который будет читать содержимое указанного файла и возвращать HTML-encoded строку. Самый простой способ:

```
public static class MyHtmlHelper
{
    public static MvcHtmlString RenderFile(string virtualPath)
    {
            var physicalPath = HostingEnvironment.MapPath(virtualPath);
            var fileContent = File.ReadAllText(physicalPath );
            return new MvcHtmlString(fileContent);
    }
}
```

Затем можно это использовать в коде представления:

```
@MyHtmlHelper.RenderFile("MyPage.html")
```

**2)** Способ №2 - это даже не способ, а скорее 'обходной путь'. Вы можете создать копию вашей html-страницы и сохранить её как view-файл. Однако здесь есть очевидный недостаток - при необходимости изменения этой страницы вам придется изменять её в двух местах.